# How do I 'use' the IteratorAggregate interface, PHP can't find it?

Tags: php, interface, iterator

I have a class that I want to implement IteratorAggregate. I declare:

```
class Email implements IteratorAggregate {
```

but when I rung the code I get:

> Attempted to load interface "IteratorAggregate" from namespace
>   "Companyname\ConsoleBundle\Entity". Did you forget a "use" statement
>   for another namespace?

So what name space should I adding to implelement the 'IteratorAggregate' interface. None of the examples I've seen include any use or require statements for it and it should be included as standard in PHP5 so it's not an installation issue.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `IteratorAggregate` is in the global namespace, so `\IteratorAggregate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use your *own* namespace and you want to use a standard class, you have to spell it like this

```
class Email implements \IteratorAggregate {
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be something stupid I had missed!

Answer (score 1):

To "use" classes from the global namespace, prefix them with a backslash:

```
use \IteratorAggregate;

class Email implements IteratorAggregate { ... }
```