# PHP Fatal error: Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found

Tags: php, google-app-engine, interface

Deploying an app to Appengine PHP 5.5 standardard environment and encountered:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found
```

No, not possible... Uploaded a quick test:

```
print_r(get_declared_interfaces());
```

Which returns:

```
[1] => iterÐnaggregate
```

But should read:

```
[1] => IteratorAggregate
```

So obviously the Interface won't be found. I've actually never seen this before? Can anyone help expand on what is going on here?

Comment: We need to see what code is failing, but is it possible [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471768/how-do-i-use-the-iteratoraggregate-interface-php-cant-find-it) is related?

Comment: @zack6849 Not doing anything too clever just `class Foo implements IteratorAggregate {// Do stuff ..}` The issue is that there appears to be some garbage in the Interface name, the Interface name is actually wrong. I took a look at the linked question you posted, unfortunately that doesn't relate – `IteratorAggregate` is in the global name space and doesn't require `use`

Comment: Just to humor me, would you try adding a \ Before the implements IteratorAggregate? eg: `class Foo implements \IteratorAggregate` and see if it works?

Comment: @zack6849 yeah absolutely, it was the first thing I tried. It really is because there's garbled characters in the Interface name. Just have no idea how to get around it.

Comment: Same error, php 5.5.34, Silex PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found in /vendor/symfony/routing/RouteCollection.php on line 26 running on App Engine standard

Comment: @iswak the issue is being tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74346494. What do you get from `print_r(get_declared_interfaces());` ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that Google declare IteratorAggregate with incorrect name.
You can check this issue by `print_r(get_declared_interfaces())`.

Resolve this by add to your php `intl.so` extension.